# Find the natural cubic spline interpolant at the nodes?

Tags: numerical-methods, spline

> Find the natural cubic spline interpolant to $f(x) = e^{x^2}$ at the nodes $\{x_i\}^2_{i=0} = \{−1, 0, 1\}$. Calculate the value of the interpolant at $x = 0.5$. What is the error at this point? S"(a) =0, S"(b) =0 : a=-1 , b=1.

---

**Ideas so far:** $S''(a) =0$, $S''(b) =0$ : $a=-1$ , $b=1$. Therefore we can say $S'(a) = f'(a)$ and $S'(b) = f'(b)$.

Then we are evaluating at $x= 0.5$. First we look at the cubic spline from $x=-1$, $x=0$ now we construct the polynomial $S_1(x) = 0.5+b_1(x-(-1))+c_1(x-(-1))^2+d_1(x-(-1)^3$. Now we take $x=0, x=1$ and construct the polynomial $S_2(x) = 0.25+b_2(x-0)+c_2(x-0)^2+d_2(x-0)^3$. The six coefficients $b_1,c_1,d_1,b_2,c_2,d_2$ are the unknowns that we need to determine. From the interpolation conditions, we get $S(0)$ and $S(1)$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is not a site to outsource homework but to answer questions you may have while solving your homework, or other tasks. What have you done so far, what tools did you use, what exactly is *your* problem?

Comment: S"(a) =0, S"(b) =0   : a=-1 , b=1. Therefore we can say S'(a) = f'(a) and S'(b) = f'(b) . Then we are evaluating at x= 0.5 . First we look at the cubic spline from x=-1 , x=0 now we construct the polynomial S1(x) = 0.5+b1(x-(-1))+c1(x-(-1))^2+d1(x-(-1)^3. Now we take x=0, x=1 and construct the polynomial S2(x) = 0.25+b2(x-0)+c2(x-0)^2+d2(x-0)^3 . The six coefficients b1,c1,d1,b2,c2,d2 are the unknowns that we need to determine. From the interpolation conditions, we get S(0) and S(1) ... I'm not sure if this is what I should be doing? @LutzL

Comment: Please add contents to the question text via the `edit` link. Further, interpolating splines only use the function values, not the derivative values of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions for the natural spline are that the cubic polynomials $S_1(x)$, $S_2(x)$ over $[-1,0]$ resp. $[0,1]$ satisfy
\begin{align}
S_1(-1)&=f(-1)\\
S_1''(-1)&=0\\
S_1(0)&=S_2(0)=f(0)\\
S_1'(0)&=S_2'(0)\\
S_1''(0)&=S_2''(0)\\
S_2(1)&=f(1)\\
S_2''(1)&=0
\end{align}
These are $8$ equations for the $8$ coefficients of the $2$ cubic polynomials.